# isNaN for parseInt() returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="val">64</div>
```

and this JS:

```
$(function(){
    console.log(isNaN(parseInt($('#val').text()))); 
})
```

and it is `false`. I need to check, if there is a number or not.

Comment: seems to work fine to me..... What value[s] fail?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Yes `false` since it's a Number..

Comment: "64" parseInt-ed is 64, and that is a number, so isN(ot)aN(umber) of course has to return false.

Comment: I think you confuse isNaN as is-Number instead of isNot-A-Number

Answer (score 2):

The `isNaN()` function returns `true` if the passed value IS NOT a number, not if IT IS a number.

Since you want to check if the given text IS a number, you can simply add a `!` in front of your `isNaN()` call so that it is testing if it is "not not" a number, or, in other words, if it IS a number:

```
$(function(){
    console.log(!isNaN(parseInt($('#val').text()))); 
})
```

The purpose of the `!` operator is to reverse the value of a Boolean; that is, change `false` to `true` and vice versa.

Comment: `!isNaN($('#val').text())` - returns `true` which means is not a number, but text in `div` is 64.

Comment: @gdfgdfg you're taking the inverse by prepending `!`

Comment: Yes, I understand, Sry 10 hours and this is the result. I think isNaN returns true, if it is number .....

Comment: @gdfgdfg isNaN returns true if it's NOT a number. However, in that example, he added a !, which flips boolean around.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the return of isNaN() function.

The global function isNaN will return **true** if the argument is not a number or **false** if the return is a number.

If you want to check if the argumet is a number you can do **!isNaN()**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the value in div is infact a number you could make it like

```
if (!isNaN(parseInt($('#val').text()))) {
  // What you want to do if it IS a number
} else {
  // What you want to do if it IS NOT a number.
}
```

You're basically checking if it's **N**ot **a** **N**umber with this function. If it IS a number, it returns `false`, and you can execute whatever code you was planning to execute, however if it's NOT a number, then it returns, `true` and you can set a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Use if statement to check if isNaN first then parse it to integer or console.log something else.

```
$(function(){
var number = !isNaN($('#val').text())?parseInt($('#val').text()):'NaN';
console.log(number);
})
```